# Iterate adding values to an existing dictionary by using a variety of keys stored as a list

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I had trouble coming up with an appropriate title for this, so apologies there.

I have an existing dictionary `di_end` which already has an order to its keys. I also have some objects which have a property containing the keys for where in `di_end` the user-entered value will go

Note: the methods `setProperty()` and `property()` are from the pyqt library where `setProperty()` creates a custom property for an object where the first argument is the name of the property and the second argument is the value for that named property and `property()` just returns the values for whatever name is passed into it as an argument.

Something like this:

```
a.setProperty('keys', [key1, key2, key3])
b.setProperty('keys', [key4, key5, key6, key7, key8])
c.setProperty('keys', [key9])
objects_list = [a, b, c]
```

I want to be able to use the keys stored in the object properties to load the value that the user enters into a field to a dictionary

I'd like to iterate the process such that these parts

```
di_end[a.property(['keys'])[0]][a.property(['keys'])[1]][a.property(['keys'])[2]] = a.value
di_end[b.property(['keys'])[0]][b.property(['keys'])[1]][b.property(['keys'])[2]]\
    [b.property(['keys'])[3]][b.property(['keys'])[4]] = b.value
di_end[c.property(['keys'])[0]] = c.value
```

or

```
a_li, b_li, c_li = a.property(['keys']), b.property(['keys']), c.property(['keys'])
di_end[a_li[0]][a_li[1]][a_li[2]] = a.value
di_end[b_li[0]][b_li[1]][b_li[2]][b_li[3]][b_li[4]] = b.value
di_end[c_li[0]] = c.value
```

do not need to be manually typed out and could be performed procedurally. I think I could do this if it was the same amount of keys but I'm not sure how to do it with differing amounts of keys. If they were all the same amounts I'd just do this

```
a.setProperty('keys', [key1, key2, key3, key4])
b.setProperty('keys', [key5, key6, key7, key8])
c.setProperty('keys', [key9, key10, key11, key12])
objects_list = [a, b, c]
a_li, b_li, c_li = a.property(['keys']), b.property(['keys']), c.property(['keys'])  # assuming all are 4 entires each
for count, item in enumerate([a_li, b_li, c_li]):
    di_end[item[0]][item[1]][item[2]][item[3]] = objects_list[count].value
```

but since there are different amounts of keys for each entry, I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Edit: Added a note about `setProperty()` and `property()`

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to tell what your code is doing here, mostly due to the `setProperty` and `property` objects, which seem awkward and not-pythonic.

That being said, this looks like yet another use case for the excellent `glom` library (`pip install glom`).

```
from glom import assign, Path

assign(data, Path(*keys), value)
```

Note that in your case

```
data = di_end
keys = a.property['keys']
value = a.value
```

and an example:

```
>>> data = {'a': {'b': {'c': 5}}}
>>> keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> value = 100
>>> assign(data, Path(*keys), value)
{'a': {'b': {'c': 100}}}
>>> data
{'a': {'b': {'c': 100}}}
```

Note that this will raise a KeyError if the path doesn't already exist.  For the generate-dict-on-demand (like a infinite nested defaultdict) style, you need to use `Assign` instead:

```
glom(data, Assign(Path(*keys), value))
```

See https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mutation.html for more details.

Comment: The property and setProperty are from pyqt5, I probably should have specified that. Its just a way to give a custom property to an object (in my case a Line Entry object). And this very well looks like it might work. I'll mess around with it a bit and report back with either questions or marking this as an answer. Thanks Ciero

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can try use recursion here. A simple example below.

*put* function creates nested dict and put value. *fetch* function can extract value from nested dict.

```
def fetch(data, keys):
  if len(keys) == 1:
    return data[keys[0]]
  return fetch(data[keys.pop()], keys)

def put(data, keys, value):
  if len(keys) == 1:
    data[keys[0]] = value
    return
  key = keys.pop()
  data[key] = {}
  put(data[key], keys, value)

di_empty = {}
keys_values = [
  (("a", "b", "c"), "abc"),
  (("b", "c", "d", "e"), "bcde")
]
for selected in keys_values:
  put(di_empty, list(reversed(selected[0])), selected[1])

di_end = dict()
di_end["a"] = {"b": {"c": "abc"}}
di_end["b"] = {"c":{"d": {"e": "bcde"}}}
keys = [("a", "b", "c"), ("b", "c", "d", "e")]
for selected in keys:
  s1 = fetch(di_end, list(reversed(selected)))
  s2 = fetch(di_empty, list(reversed(selected)))
  assert s1 == s2
  print(s1)
  print(s2)
```